# How to set 3 attribute is unique of model

Tags: yii2, unique, rules

I have a model `TblPayroll` with the above attributes, I want to check uniqueness of `'fk_int_emp_id'` , `'fk_int_payroll_month'`, `'fk_int_payroll_year'`. If this three fields already in database it should not insert. At least one is different it should insert. How can I check the uniqueness?

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'pk_int_payroll_id' => 'Payroll Id',
            'fk_int_emp_id' => 'Employee',
            'vchr_worked_hours' => 'Worked Hours',
            'vchr_actual_hours' => 'Actual Hours',
            'fk_int_payroll_month' => 'Month',
            'fk_int_payroll_year' => 'Year',
        ];
    }

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[ 'vchr_worked_hours', 'vchr_actual_hours', 'fk_int_payroll_month', 'fk_int_payroll_year'], 'required'],

            //[['fk_int_emp_id', 'fk_int_payroll_year','vchr_worked_hours','vchr_actual_hours'], 'integer'],
            //[['fk_int_emp_id','fk_int_payroll_month','fk_int_payroll_year'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['fk_int_emp_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TblEmployee::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['fk_int_emp_id' => 'pk_int_emp_id']],
            [['fk_int_payroll_month'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TblPayrollMonth::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['fk_int_payroll_month' => 'pk_int_payroll_month_id']],
            [['fk_int_payroll_year'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TblPayrollYear::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['fk_int_payroll_year' => 'pk_int_payroll_year_id']],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: @scaiseEdge check this

Comment: you have set unique attribute in rules not labels, show us rules section.

Comment: please check the edited ones, i need to insert this model but while insert  'fk_int_emp_id' , 'fk_int_payroll_month', 'fk_int_payroll_year'  it should be unique at sametime. if anyone different in this three fields it should insert...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[['fk_int_emp_id', 'fk_int_payroll_month', 'fk_int_payroll_year'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['fk_int_emp_id', 'fk_int_payroll_month', 'fk_int_payroll_year'], 'message' => 'The combination of .... has already been taken.'],
```